# Java: using TOR as proxy

Tags: java, proxy, tor

I am trying to use TOR as a proxy in my Java application. Here's the basic code that I am using for testing:

```
SocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",9050);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,sockAddr);
        URL url = new URL("https://check.torproject.org/");
        //URL url = new URL("https://api.ipify.org/");
        url.openConnection(proxy);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] stuff = new byte[1024];
        int readBytes = 0;
        while((readBytes = in.read(stuff))>0) {
            bout.write(stuff,0,readBytes);
        }
        byte[] result = bout.toByteArray();
        System.out.print(new String(result));
```

The result string is -

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>

  Sorry. You are not using Tor.
</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/torcheck/img/tor-off.png" />
```

(removed the rest as it's not relevant). The Tor service is running on my PC

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:9050          *:*                     LISTEN
```

What went wrong?

****UPDATE****

Alright, so I got it to work by making a tiny change in the code.

```
InputStream in = url.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream();
```

Instead of calling openStream() on a URL object on which openConnection(Proxy) has been called, the code now calls getInputStream() after the connection is opened.
This is definitely working, as the TOR status page now tells me I am connected, the IP address page gives me an address that is not my own, and I can even read data from onion pages now.

However, I don't understand why it didn't work before. Aren't the two codes doing the exact same thing?